# Linq intellisense Missing on EF Object

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, intellisense

I'm facing a strange type of issue.

In my VS Solution I have 3 projects.

1. ASP.Net App
2. C# Class Library (Used as my DAL and contains a EF .edmx file.
3. Windows Service App

The ASP.Net App can succesffully access the the EF Model and I can use either classic Linq or Lambda .First() etc. Everything works fine.

On my Windows Service App, I've added a reference to the DAL DLL , but for some reason, the Intellisense does not show up when I type in any code files in the windows service library. Example of my code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace alertservice
{    
    class AlertPolling
    {
        dal.applicationEntities ent;
        public AlertPolling()
        {
            ent = new dal.applicationEntities();
            ent.Queries.   // <--- ZERO INTELLISENSE HAPPENING HERE.
        }
        public void StartPolling()
        {      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same thing happens when I try : 
var collection = from n in ent.Queries where n.

Comment: Try adding a reference to `System.Data`. EF depends on this assembly and it may be required for the intellisense to work as expected.

Comment: Does the code compile if you type it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys. I managed to fix the problem by following the comments from flipchart.

I added a reference to System.Data.Entity which fixed it. Intellisense now coming up.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me.  Saved me after an hour of swearing. @Fox you should mark it as the correct answer.